# creating Android Virtual Device (AVD) in eclipse 3.5 on windows xp

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have stacked here, because i am totally new in android world. Can show the way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is all explained by Google [right here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use Android SDK 1.6 and AVD 0.9.3 - [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/1.6_r1/index.html)
It has an AVD and SDK manager.